# My python script in generating a error, even if all variables are int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an error in the line of `return` (in module 'average')
As you can see, I've already tried to surround everything with `int()`.

Here is the code:

```
g_grade_list = []
k_grade_list = []

def g_sum():
    s = 0
    for i in g_grade_list:
        s += int(i)

    return s

def k_sum():
    s = 0
    for i in k_grade_list:
        s += int(i)

    return s

def average():
    g_grade = input("Geben Sie Ihre Grundnoten ein.")
    k_grade = input("Geben Sie Ihre Klausurnoten ein.")
    wert = input("Geben Sie die Wertigkkeit der Klausurnoten ein.(in %)")

    g_grade_list.extend(g_grade.split(','))
    g_grade_avg = int((g_sum() * len(g_grade_list)))

    k_grade_list.extend(k_grade.split(','))
    k_grade_avg = int((k_sum() * len(k_grade_list)))

    return ((k_grade_avg * int(int(wert) / int(100)) + (g_grade_avg * int(1 - (int(wert / int(100)))))))

average()
```

Note: The Inputs are always complete numbers (1,2,3...).

The Error code:

```
  return ((k_grade_avg * int(int(wert) / int(100)) + (g_grade_avg * int(1 - (int(wert / int(100)))))))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `wert` is a string and you're trying to do `wert / int(100)`. You don't need to convert 100 to an int, but you do need to convert `wert`.

Comment: It would be much easier for you to separate  this expression to a few variables to see what's going on. 7 closing parenthesis in a row are a good sign for that

Comment: Also, note that `int(100)` is useless, `100` is already an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is `wert`.

You’re initializing the variable here:

```py
wert = input("Geben Sie die Wertigkkeit der Klausurnoten ein.(in %)")
```

and use it here:

```py
return ((k_grade_avg * int(int(wert) / int(100)) + (g_grade_avg * int(1 - (int(wert / int(100)))))))
```

Let me point out the specific operation which fails:

```py
wert / int(100)
```

---

As you maybe already found out: the `input` function returns a string, which is why `wert / 100` fails. You're trying to divide a string (`wert`) through a number.

If you wrap `wert` in `int` this particular snippet will work - for as long as you provide a valid number, if you give something else (like `abc`) your program will crash.

I would like to point out, that you would most likely have found this error earlier if this particular line (`return ...`) had been shorter. You might consider splitting up the various operations into multiple lines to not loose sight of the bigger picture.